# Apache + FreeBSD+Ruby Rails Configuration Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, apache2, freebsd

I have installed FreeBsd and configured Ruby on Rails Application Successfully im my localhost. The project is running perfectly using the 'Webrick' server .
But i have issues in configuring **apache** .

I have installed apache22 and apache is working. When i enter http:localhost am getting a page which displays 'It Works'.

Then when i enter my application http:\localhost\myapp it shows 404 Invalid request URl error. i dont know how to set the path.

My  applcation is placed in folder \usr\home\virtualbsd\myapp

Below is my http.conf file .. Any help is appreciated

ServerRoot "/usr/local"

Listen 80

```
LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache22/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache22/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache22/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_default_module libexec/apache22/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module libexec/apache22/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_default_module libexec/apache22/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache22/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache22/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule file_cache_module libexec/apache22/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache22/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module libexec/apache22/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache22/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache22/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache22/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache22/mod_filter.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module libexec/apache22/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache22/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache22/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache22/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache22/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache22/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module libexec/apache22/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache22/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache22/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache22/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache22/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache22/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache22/mod_version.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache22/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache22/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache22/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache22/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache22/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache22/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module libexec/apache22/mod_info.so
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache22/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache22/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache22/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache22/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache22/mod_dir.so
LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache22/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache22/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache22/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache22/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache22/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache22/mod_rewrite.so

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache22/libphp5.so
LoadModule suphp_module       libexec/apache22/mod_suphp.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby18


<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User www
Group www

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin admin@your-domain.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

ServerName localhost

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
#DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data"

DocumentRoot "/usr/home/virtualbsd/myapp"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/usr/home/virtualbsd/myapp">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Comment: @shingara. Any idea abt this ?

Answer (score 0):

I **think** you might need to add an alias:

Add this to your httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /myapp "/usr/home/virtualbsd/myapp"

<Directory "/usr/home/virtualbsd/myapp">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```